# Java Swing - Check If Apps Is Not Update or Have a New Version

Tags: java, swing, auto-update

I'm currently working on a big project that will publish alot version,
but My apps always will update, and i already publish it.

Someone my user don't know if my apps have update if he don't check website and looking for new version.

Anyway, to solve this problem i have a idea to make from confirm when user open apps and it have new latest version, and will confirm asking for update or no.

But the problem, how to check if user apps is not latest version?

Comment: 1. Your app needs some way to determine what version it is, maybe via a internal configuration file which is updated at build/release time. 2. You need somewhere that you app can ask what the current version currently is, maybe a web service for example.  Of course, you could forego all the pain and have a look at something like [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) which can check for and download updates itself

Comment: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS not only offers automatic update checks, but also programmatic control of updates & information on whether there are newer versions of app. components available.  No need to reinvent the wheel..